# Convert ImageMagick command to Wand Python

Tags: python, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, wand

I'm wondering how to convert this working command line sequence from ImageMagick into a Python script using the Wand library:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert pic.png -alpha off +dither -colors 2 -colorspace gray -normalize -statistic median 1x200 -negate -format "%[fx:mean*w*h]" info:
```

My current Python code is:

```
with Image(filename= 'pic.png') as img:
    with img.clone() as img_copy1:
        img_copy1.alpha_channel = False
        img_copy1.quantize(number_colors= 2, colorspace_type='gray', dither= True)
        img_copy1.normalize()
        img_copy1.negate(grayscale= True)
```

But I still don't know how to compute the number of pixels that is part of the vertical feature...

**UPDATE:**

I modified my code thanks to @fmw42

```
with wand.image.Image(filename='pic.png') as img:
    with img.clone() as img_copy1:
        img_copy1.alpha_channel = False
        img_copy1.quantize(number_colors= 2, colorspace_type='gray', dither= True)
        img_copy1.normalize()
        img_copy1.statistic("median", width = 1, height = 200)
        img_copy1.negate()
        img.options['format'] = '%[fx:mean*w*h]'
        print(img.make_blob('INFO'))
```

Comment: Why do you have img_copy1.negate()? I see no -negate in your command line?

Comment: Sure there is, just before the -format

Comment: On the command-line, `+dither` will **disable** dithering, so surely you'd want `dither=False` in **Wand**.

Comment: Also, in your command-line version, when you quantize to 2 colours you are doing so in a coloured colourspace then converting the result to greyscale, whereas in **Wand** (I think) you are going to greyscale first, then quantizing to 2 colours - which is potentially/probably different.

Comment: In order to debug, I would chop off everything after `-normalize` and add `DEBUG-cmdline.PNG` then in **Wand** save the intermediate image after normalising as `DEBUG-wand.PNG` and compare the two.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that I got a while back from Eric McConville (the Wand developer) for doing fx: computations. This should give you a clue how to do yours.

```
from wand.image import Image
with Image(filename='zelda.png') as img:
  img.options['format'] = '%wx%h'
  print(img.make_blob('INFO'))
```

Eric can comment further if there is a better way to do that now.

Comment: It works, thank you. I still don't get the same figures when I run the command in the shell and when I run the Python script... I will investigate more on that

Comment: How much different are they?

Comment: When I run the script I get 2.47268e+07 while I get 5.34519e+06 in the command line

Comment: See Mark Setchell's comments above. Perhaps that will resolve the differences.